# Set Spring logging file in tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, tomcat8

I have a Spring Boot app with the following application.yml

```
logging:
  file: logs/api.log
  pattern:
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0} : %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    guru.springframework.controllers: INFO
    org.hibernate: INFO
```

which works fine in tomcat 7 and the api.log file was under /logs directory

when I move the app to tomcat 8.5 all the logs are going to catalina.out

I tried also with

```
logging:
  path: /logs
  file: api.log
```

I made a global search for api.log but the file does not exist on the server

Comment: path: logs, don't add slash

Comment: nope ... it doesn't even create the file, i run  ```find . -name "api*"``` on the server and the file doesn't exist